# How to write this void objective-c function in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, swift

I've found code that I want to use in a swift ios app but I'm having trouble writing it the swift way.

```
-(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer( sampleBuffer );
    CGSize imageSize = CVImageBufferGetEncodedSize( imageBuffer );
    // also in the 'mediaSpecific' dict of the sampleBuffer

   NSLog( @"frame captured at %.fx%.f", imageSize.width, imageSize.height );
}
```

It's just the function declaration I'm having trouble with, the contents of the function should be easier. I'm not used to the syntax of:

```
    -(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
```

My attempt:

I started trying to write it like this but when nothing would autocomplete within the `()` I realised it was definitely wrong:

```
func captureOutput(AVCaptureOutput(didOutputSampleBuffer:)) {

}
```

Comment: Post your swift code attempt?

Comment: Added my own attempt

Comment: Isn't this a valid question? Why the down vote plus close?

Comment: You should read an introductory Swift tutorial if you don't even know the correct syntax for function parameters.

Comment: The question shows no effort in attempting to solve the problem. And your current "own attempt" proves even less effort have been spent on learning Swift.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html). Also if you start typing the method name it should autocomplete.

Comment: see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate/captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the correct declaration in the [*AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate Protocol Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate/captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:), where it is declared like this:

```
optional func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,
    didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,
    fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

You wouldn't write `optional` in your method definition, though:

```
class MyDelegate: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    func captureOutput(captureOutput:AVCaptureOutput,
        didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer,
        fromConnection connection:AVCaptureConnection) {

            let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            let imageSize = CVImageBufferGetEncodedSize(imageBuffer)

            NSLog("frame captured at %.fx%.f", imageSize.width, imageSize.height)
    }

}
```